# Frequency table of two variables as percentage of whole sample

Tags: stata

I have two variables:

1. `Married`, which is either Married or Not Married
2. `Race`, which is Black, White, or Other

I'm trying to find the *percent* of `Married` and `Black` within the *whole* population.

I have tried the following code:

```
tab married race, row

   married |     black      other      white |     Total
-----------+---------------------------------+----------
   married |       274         18      1,150 |     1,442 
           |     19.00       1.25      79.75 |    100.00 
-----------+---------------------------------+----------
    single |       309          8        487 |       804 
           |     38.43       1.00      60.57 |    100.00 
-----------+---------------------------------+----------
     Total |       583         26      1,637 |     2,246 
           |     25.96       1.16      72.89 |    100.00
```

However, I'm looking for 274/2246, not 274/1442 which is what the `19.00` gives me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this directly with the `cell` option:

```
sysuse auto, clear

tabulate foreign rep78, cell

+-----------------+
| Key             |
|-----------------|
|    frequency    |
| cell percentage |
+-----------------+

           |                   Repair Record 1978
  Car type |      Poor       Fair    Average       Good  Excellent |     Total
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
  Domestic |         2          8         27          9          2 |        48 
           |      2.90      11.59      39.13      13.04       2.90 |     69.57 
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
   Foreign |         0          0          3          9          9 |        21 
           |      0.00       0.00       4.35      13.04      13.04 |     30.43 
-----------+-------------------------------------------------------+----------
     Total |         2          8         30         18         11 |        69 
           |      2.90      11.59      43.48      26.09      15.94 |    100.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is with the *community-contributed*  command `groups` from the *Stata Journal*.

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. groups foreign rep78

  +------------------------------------+
  |  foreign   rep78   Freq.   Percent |
  |------------------------------------|
  | Domestic       1       2      2.90 |
  | Domestic       2       8     11.59 |
  | Domestic       3      27     39.13 |
  | Domestic       4       9     13.04 |
  | Domestic       5       2      2.90 |
  |------------------------------------|
  |  Foreign       3       3      4.35 |
  |  Foreign       4       9     13.04 |
  |  Foreign       5       9     13.04 |
  +------------------------------------+
```

Note that -- unlike `tabulate` -- `groups` can do this for general multi-way tables. See https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1403309-groups-updated-on-ssc for an overview. That thread contains references to a write-up in the *Stata Journal* in 2017.

At the time of writing, the latest version can be downloaded either with `ssc install groups` or using the clickable link yielded by `search st0496_1, entry`.